# Как правильно подключить bootstrap к jsp странице используя пакет webjars?

Tags: java, bootstrap, jsp, spring-mvc

В Maven указываю следующие зависимости

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>${bootstrap.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Затем добавляю в ресурсы

```
public void addResourceHandler(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}
```

Затем задаю конфигурацию в JSP

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath} webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>Cloud statistic</title>
```

Далее подключаю обязательные скрипты, с указанием пути библиотеки.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js</script>
```

Что характерно, каких бы то ни было проблем с видимостью нет, ошибок тоже нет. Но при этом коды компонентов взятых с сайта bootstrap не подключаются. Нашел уже кучу примеров, но безуспешно.
Может я что-то сделал не так?

Comment: Какой путь к CSS-файлу у вас получается в итоге? `${pageContext.request.contextPath} webjars` выглядит некорректно, не пропустили ли вы здесь слэш?

Comment: @SlavaSemushin, нет не пропустил. Беда в том что я только уже не делал, ноль реакции

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `jquery` есть уже поновее версия, и, надеюсь, у Вас `${bootstrap.version} = 3.3.7`
2. Тут попробуйте сделать так:

   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">`
3. Если добавить такую зависимость:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
      <version>0.32</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

   то можно будет упростить до:

   ```
   <link rel='stylesheet' href='/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
   ```
4. Добавьте слэш:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js</script>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил путем подключения в зависимости Excludes

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>${bootstrap.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```